# finding a solution to a giving maze txt.file

Tags: python

how can i fix this program, the problem is when it print out the coordinate it give me a 7 for the start and finish, i would appreciated you help, thanks

```
start = (len(data))
finish = (len(data))
pos= []
for i in range(len(pos)):
    for j in range(len(pos[i])):
        if pos[i][j] == "S":
            start=(i,j)

        elif  pos[i][j] == "F":
            finish=(i,j)

print "S found in",start,
print "\nF found in",finish,"\n"
```

Comment: when i run this program, when it print the coordinates it print out the coordinate for start and finish a 7 it should be for start (3,4) and finish (0,2) coordinate

Comment: Ehm... Please, be more specific on what you are asking.

Comment: this is a maze and i need to the get the coordinates for the start and finish but im printing them first but is not printing what i want.

Comment: this is the program 

    start = (len(data))
    finish = (len(data))
    pos= []
    for i in range(len(pos)):
        for j in range(len(pos[i])):
            if pos[i][j] == "S":
                start=(i,j)
    
            elif  pos[i][j] == "F":
                finish=(i,j)

    print "S found in",start,
    print "\nF found in",finish,"\n"

Comment: edited to fix the code formatting.

Comment: @alberto, it's impossible to format code readably in comments -- plus, why ever would you want to repeat in a comment all the code you already have in the question (which I reformatted for you)?!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the start of your code:

```
start = (len(data))
finish = (len(data))
pos= []
for i in range(len(pos)):
```

`len(pos)` is zero, of course (you've just assigned the empty list to `pos`, so **what else** could that length **possibly** be but 0?!), so the loop executes zero times, `start` and `finish` never change, and what you print for them after the loop is exactly what you assigned to them here -- and despite all the redundant parentheses that's just the same integer for both (which you tell us is `7`, so presumably whatever `data` is, it has a length of 7).

Comment: i just figured out that 7 is the # of lines in the txt files, how can i fix this ?

Comment: the txt files has 7 lines and 10 element in each lines.

Comment: You could try **using** that `data` list -- you never use it anywhere in your code (except for the two calls to `len` at the start), rather you're assigning an empty list to `pos` then "using" `pos` (which obviously does nothing). Whatever problem related to `data` you want to solve, how can you possibly even _dream_ of solving it while never, ever **using** what `data` contains?!

Comment: @alberto, you can change your code with any text editor of your choice.  Presumably you should change it to remove the silly assignment to `pos` and change all uses of `pos` into uses of `data`.

Comment: Oh, and, instead of the weird initialization of start and finish, just assign `None` to each of them at the start.